# Should one use built in classes?

Tags: c++, stl

I've started programming C++ and I want to start programming useful stuff.

I know that for strings, one can use `std::string` or `char`-arrays. One can also use `std::vectors` as well, instead of arrays.

What should one do? Reinvent the wheel, or use the built in utilities?

The point of the question is to find out what people actually do. Do people use the STL a lot or do people use `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: "Reinvent the wheel, or use the built in utilities?" Take a guess.

Comment: Did you build the wheels for your car on your own, or you bought the ready ones from the store? If you didn't reinvent the wheels literally, why are you considering it metaphorically?

Comment: @littleadv: that's not a good analogy. Unless he built his car.

Comment: Of course you should reinvent the wheel, we need another square one out here! To be serious: It helps to have implemented some things on your own to know what is going on inside but in production this will only introduce more errors. So use the utilities! They aren't exhibits that you are not allowed to touch.

Answer (score 5):

Reinventing the wheel can be good as a training assignment, but If you want to write useful stuff - of course use the standard library ("the built in utilities").

The standard library (as well as [boost](http://www.boost.org/), and other libraries) is validated and optimized, and it will let you write the useful stuff much easier, so you can focus on your logic instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes and no. There is a lot to learn from seeing how they are implemented, but chances are that your own implementation of a string will have quite a few flaws even if it seems to work (exception safe? self assignment safe?)... Of course that might teach you the basics, but there is no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Always use standard libraries (STLs, Boost, etc) unless there is a reason for doing otherwise (e.g STL not available on platform). These libraries are time tested for both correctness and performance

Comment: The "STL" is an anachronism. The C++ standard library contains most of what people refer to as the STL, and it is part of the language, hence available in all compliant C++ implementations.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to program useful and stable software, use the standard libraries.

If your goal is to explore a specific topic, such as strings, then reinvent the string class and learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Wow, thank you for giving me a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Usse the built in utilities. They are optimized and will ensure that your code is fully portable!

Note that you should use them skillfully: vectors can be rendered WAY faster if you reserve space before using them, etc.